# libx264.so.146 not found while compiling C++ code or x264 itself

Tags: c++, ubuntu, x264

I just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 15.10 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Now, for some reason my C++ project won't compile anymore. CLion keeps saying it's missing 'libx264.so.146 as you can see in the compile log:

```
/home/lorre851/CLion/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/lorre851/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/ce7171e4/ce7171e4/Release --target main -- -j 8
[ 20%] Linking CXX executable build/main
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libx264.so.146, needed by /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_146'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_close'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_bit_depth'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_headers'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_encode'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_reconfig'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_param_parse'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_profile'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_param_apply_fastfirstpass'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_levels'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_picture_init'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_param_default'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_param_default_preset'
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.57: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_delayed_frames'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'build/main' failed
make[3]: *** [build/main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

Most people seem to give 'reinstalling x264' as a solution. However, reinstalling x264 with the following commands leads to the same error while compiling x264 itself.

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --enable-static
make

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libx264.so.146, needed by /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so: undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_146'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:202: recipe for target 'x264' failed
make: *** [x264] Error 1
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could get around this?

Comment: Where does the libav library in /usr/local/lib originate from? This is not a system lib but most likely one you have installed. This one is linked to an older x264 lib which is is not available on 16.04. You probably need to recompile this libav library or use the libav installed by Ubuntu itself.

Comment: Florian's comment should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a day of trying to remove and recompile the liavcodec-dev library, without result, I decided to format the drive and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.

Everything is working fine now.